# Inject logger in EJB with jboss 5

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jboss5.x

Hey guys and gals. How can i inject custom Logger in EJB i'm using jboss 5 ga.

Answer (score 0):

- Make the custom logger an EJB and
  inject it using @EJB annotation
  (assuming you are using EJB 3.0+).
- Use an IoC such as Spring or Guice

Comment: i was thinking something like: custom annotation and interceptor that set the field in the EJB using reflection but i think there is better way